# What are the red glowing towers in Zoltun Kulle's archives?

Tags: diablo-iii

They look like this:

[image: Red glowing thing]

If I hit them they explode and then reform, and they appear to spit out a bit of blood.

Comment: To my knowledge, they're just there as an extra "destruction" bit.  I don't believe there's any lore or anything else that mentions them.

Comment: @Frank you should write this as an answer.

Comment: Thanks @kalina, I did several searches but didn't find that one.